# Change toggle button on click?

Tags: html, css, button, toggle

Burger menu icon opens and closes a hidden sidebar, at the same time I want the icon to change to an X when the sidebar is open.

Button

```
<span style="font-size:16px;cursor:pointer" onclick="toggleNav()"><i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fas fa-bars"></i> </span>
```

Menu Scripts

```
<script>
function toggleNav() {
    var sidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav"),
    main = document.getElementById("main");
    sidenav.style.width = sidenav.style.width === "250px" ? '0' : '250px';
    wrapper.style.marginLeft = wrapper.style.marginLeft === "250px" ? 'auto' :  '250px';
}
</script>

<script>
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fas fa-times");
}
</script>
```

Probably making a glaringly obvious mistake but I've googled as many times as I can and still can't figure it out.

Comment: Hello, what is wrapper ?

Comment: Content of the board, so the content I'm pushing to the side when the sidebar extends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot toggle multiple classes like you did

You have to do two calls

```js
function toggleNav() {
  /*    var sidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav"),
      main = document.getElementById("main");
      sidenav.style.width = sidenav.style.width === "250px" ? '0' : '250px';
      wrapper.style.marginLeft = wrapper.style.marginLeft === "250px" ? 'auto' :  '250px';*/
}

function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-bars");
  x.classList.toggle("fa-times");
}
```

```css
i {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size:16px;cursor:pointer" onclick="toggleNav()"><i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fas fa-bars"></i> The red square represent your icon</span>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, was sure it was something like that!